# how to do a filter from a table where 2 different columns has 2 different records which has same set of key combinations in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates

I am working with millions of data where i wanted to filter 2 different columns having 2 different records for the same set of key combination,

The table looks like :

| SK | NO | NAME | DOB | TS | EFF_DT | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-03T00:00:00 | 24-03 | ABC |
| 123 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-03T12:00:00 | 24-05 | ABC |
| 456 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-04T00:00:00 | 14-03 | CBA |
| 456 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-04T12:00:00 | 14-03 | CBA |

I wanted to filter the records based on key columns combinations that is SK and NO columns are same for different TS and eff_dt  and not wanted pick records where TS is alone different.

can someone please explain on how to achieve this?

thanks in advance!

The expected output:

| SK | NO | NAME | DOB | TS | EFF_DT | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-03T00:00:00 | 24-03 | ABC |
| 123 | 1 | Thomas | 1/12/1994 | 2024-29-03T12:00:00 | 24-05 | ABC |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, we identify combinations of **SK** and **NO** that have two unique values in two separate columns using the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses :

```
SELECT SK, `NO`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY SK, `NO`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TS) = 2 AND  COUNT(DISTINCT EFF_DT) = 2
```

Then, to obtain the desired results, we merge this with the original table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT SK, `NO`
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY SK, `NO`
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TS) = 2 AND  COUNT(DISTINCT EFF_DT) = 2
) AS s ON s.SK = t.SK AND s.NO = t.NO
```